# Express nodejs POST method return empty brackets

Tags: node.js, express, post

I can't get the value in my form. I am using a basic HTML form to send my data. When I try to test the return of the POST method in the console, I can't find the value of my input. This is my code:

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

// Moteur de template
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Middleware
app.use('/assets', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());


// Routes
app.get('/',  (request, response) => {
    response.render('pages/index');
});

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

my console always return {}

Comment: You don't have body-parser imported

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your answers. In fact Body-parser is deprecated and is actually integrated with Express. In fact I'm a bit ashamed, I made a beginner's mistake (I am, by the way). In my form, I forgot to put the "name" attribute in the input ... the problem came from there otherwise everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the front of your code:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended : true}));

app.use(express.json());
```

`body-parser` is no longer needed, as this feature is already provided in express.js.

also I would suggest you to do `const express = require('express'); const app = express();` instead of `let express = require('express'); let app = express();`.

Answer (score 0):

Do `npm install 'body-parser`

Then update your code like this

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
// For FORM input
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Moteur de template
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Middleware
app.use('/assets', express.static('public'));

// Body parser For forms Actions 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Routes
app.get('/',  (request, response) => {
    response.render('pages/index');
});

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

This should fix it